# Python: No module named 'gdal_merge'

Tags: gdal, merge

I try to merge two DEM data sets with python, using `gdal_merge`, but it doesn't work. I install like this:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

But this doesn't work:

```
import gdal_merge as gm
```

I get the error message:

> No module named 'gdal_merge'

I am entirely new to Python

Comment: gdal_warp is its own Python script, so it *uses* the gdal package but it's not actually part of it.  You'll notice it's [not listed in the docs](https://gdal.org/python/), unlike some of the non-Python utilities that are wrapped into the API such as `gdal.Translate()`

Comment: Hm. I tried to import it as
from osgeo import gdal_warp
import gdal_warp
but this failed. I guess I need a more basic understanding

Comment: What I mean is that by default you can't import it at all, because it's not part of the osgeo module.  It wouldn't be "best practice" by any means, but If you're brand new to Python the easiest way to get going will be to copy/paste the [source of gdal_edit](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_edit.py) into your own script so you can call the function.  Otherwise you'll need to alter the path so Python can find that file for import